# Crossdomain service access from JS

Tags: javascript, wcf, dns

I have a web page, from which i want to access some WCF service.
The `document.domain` property on that page is equal to
 `sb3.sb2.sb1.mydomain.com`

From that page i want to send a POST request to WCF service, that located at:

`sb4.mydomain.com`

So the common part for both is only `mydomain.com`
And i have a 405 Network Error - Method not Allowed.

I've tried to force via js `document.domain = "mydomain.com";`

But still have same issue.

It is possible to solve it and how?

EDIT: Ask for admins to rename web site domain to

```
sb3.sb2.sb1.sb4.mydomain.com
```

So that web page would have a 'child' domain of service domain.
Let know if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the endpoint accepts POST requests?

Comment: Yes, when domains are equals (on other project) same service works ok